# Clickhouse: 0 for absent aggregate

Tags: clickhouse

Imagine there is a table:

```
code | value
------------
AAAA | 10
AAAA | 15
BBBB | 5
```

I would like to count (aggregate) by code and for absent codes counted value to 0:

```
select code, count(*) count
from table
where code in ('AAAA', 'CCCC')
group by code
```

The actual result for query above:

```
code | count
------------
AAAA | 2
```

But I'd expect result to be:

```
code | count
------------
AAAA | 2
CCCC | 0
```

Is it possible to archive expected result? If yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT `F`.`code`, IFNULL(`AT`.`count`, 0) as `count` FROM 
( 
  SELECT `code`, count(*) as `count` FROM `table` 
  WHERE `code` IN ('AAAA', 'CCCC') group by `code`
) as `AT`
RIGHT JOIN 
(
  SELECT 'AAAA' as `code`
  UNION 
  SELECT 'CCCC' as `code`
) as `F`
ON `F`.`code` = `AT`.`code`
```

Follow this [SQL fiddel](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a69b6f/13).